# Dijkstras algorithm using HashMap - How to insert nodes generated from adjacency graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I have a written a class called `Adjacency` and it reads a .txt file that contains different cities with distances to neighbours. Example of a few entries are

```
...
Lede     Alst     7
Alst     Merelbeke     26
Merelbeke     Alst     26
Alst     Ninove     13
Ninove     Alst     13
...
```

`Adjacency` is about 130 lines of code, I could paste it upon request. Now, once run it prints out in the command the following lines

```
...
Lebbeke --> Aalst[14.0], Asse[12.0], Buggenhout[6.0]
Aalter --> Aalst[49.0], Asse[63.0]
...
```

which is simply the distance from Lebbeke and Aalter to their negihbours. I now want to use this result along with Dijkstras algorithm and `HashMap` in order to find the closest path only from the inputs `start` node and `stop` node.

I've seen a lot of examples of using Dijkstras algorithm, but they only ever use integers as nodes but I want the nodes to be able to be anything using `HashMap` to look up the nodes.

**My idea is this:**

I create a `HashMap` where each key is the node, and each value is an `ArrayList` (or `List`) containing all the neighbours. Also, in all the tutorials they initiate the starting node with `0` and the rest of the nodes with infinity. However, since I can't know in beforehand how many unvisited nodes there are, (because I'll be reading in files that each have different number of nodes) I can't initialize them to infinity. What should I initialize them as? Just a very large number?

In my class PathFinder I have the method Dijkstra which I want to implement.

```
public class PathFinder<Node> {

    private DirectedGraph<Node> graph;
    private long startTimeMillis;

    public PathFinder(DirectedGraph<Node> graph) {
        this.graph = graph;
    }

    public class Result<Node> {
        public final boolean success;
        public final Node start;
        public final Node goal;
        public final double cost;
        public final List<Node> path;
        public final int visitedNodes;
        public final double elapsedTime;

        public Result(boolean success, Node start, Node goal, double cost, List<Node> path, int visitedNodes) {
            this.success = success;
            this.start = start;
            this.goal = goal;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.path = path;
            this.visitedNodes = visitedNodes;
            this.elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis) / 1000.0;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String s = "";
            s += String.format("Visited nodes: %d\n", visitedNodes);
            s += String.format("Elapsed time: %.1f seconds\n", elapsedTime);
            if (success) {
                s += String.format("Total cost from %s -> %s: %s\n", start, goal, cost);
                s += "Path: " + path.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" -> "));
            } else {
                s += String.format("No path found from %s", start);
            }
            return s;
        }
        public Result<Node> search(String algorithm, V start, V goal) {
            startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            switch (algorithm) {
            case "random":   return searchRandom(start, goal);
            case "dijkstra": return searchDijkstra(start, goal);
            case "astar":    return searchAstar(start, goal);
           }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown search algorithm: " + algorithm);
        }

   public Result<Node> Dijkstra(Node start, Node goal) {

      int visitedNodes = 0;
      Node current = start;

      ArrayList<Double> distanceToNeighbour = new ArrayList<Double>();
      distanceToNeighbour.add(/*Here I need to find the neigbours, get the distances and put them in*/);

      HashMap<Node, ArrayList<Double>> nodesToCosts = new HashMap<Node, ArrayList<Double>>();
      nodesToCosts.put(/*Here I need to loop through all the nodes and put one at a time*/, distanceToNeighbour)

      // ... and then I proceed with the algorithm here.

      return new Result<>(false, start, null, -1, null, visitedNodes);
    }
}
```

So as you can see my problem boils down to two things:

1. How do I get the nodes from Adjacency and put them as keys in my HashMap?
2. How do I find all the neighbours of all the nodes and find the distances to them? (these are actually the edges of the graph that I want to put in the `ArrayList` corresponding to each key/node.)

Any help on a good start is welcome. After this I believe I can complete the algorithm myself. If my question is not good, please give me feedback on how to improve it.

Comment: https://github.com/KushtrimPacaj/kp-googlefoobar/blob/master/src/Challenge3.java

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you read the file line by line to get three pieces of data:

`StartCity, Neighbor, Distance`

Tokenize these three pieces of information, and add to the hashmap with `StartCity` as `Key`.
You will need some structure to holde the 2-tuple of [Neighbor, Distance]. The `Value` of your `HashMap` will be a `List<2-tuple>`.

Comment: So why can't the holder of my 2-tuple also be a HashMap? I'm not sure what a good structure for holding a 2-tuple is.

Comment: Sure, a HashMap would work just fine. As long as the neighbors of a given city are unique, that will work. If not, you will just overwrite the distances.